Google Script to undo change if the change was empty cell ("")
I have a form that sends data to Google Sheets.  It sends data to columns A through O of the Google Sheet.  Only columns A, E, H, J, L, and O ends up being valid values.  I have a Google Script to adjust the format to the cells in those columns, except O.  That part of the code works fine.  The other columns of the sheet have blank values ("") passed into the cells.  Google Sheet Screen Shot
I would like to undo the changes and return the cell back to the old value if the passed value == "".  This would be the yellow columns in the attached screen shot. I'm not sure how to apply this change to my script.  Can someone help with the code to undo the change to the cell in columns B, F, G, K, and M (the cells that have "" passed into them)?
This is what I have so far.
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const ss = e.source;
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  const origValue = e.oldValue
  var excludes = ['ALL','Offices'];
  
  //exits the function if the active sheet name belongs to the blacklist
  if (excludes.includes(sheet.getName())) {
    return;
  }
  sheet.getRange("A5:A").setNumberFormat("m-d-yyyy");
  sheet.getRange("H5:H").setNumberFormat('h":"mm" "am/pm');
  sheet.getRange("J5:J").setNumberFormat('h":"mm" "am/pm');
  sheet.getRange("E5:E").setNumberFormat("0");
  sheet.getRange("L5:L").setNumberFormat("0");

  if(e.value == "")
  sheet.getRange('B5:B').setValue(origValue);
}


I must admit that I am curious about why you want to do this - but I guess that is your business. What you haven't explained is what format you applied to cell in columns B, F, G, K, and M. 1) Would you please edit the question to include the script that assigns the formats in the first instance. 2) Regarding the included script, what is the relevance of var excludes = ['ALL','Offices'];. 3) Are you proposing to onSelectionChange as a trigger? Why not write a script for any existing data, and modify the existing script for new submissions?

Copy of Google Script to undo cell change if changed value == "". See Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites.

The onSelectionChange(e) simple trigger is probably not the right trigger to use. It is unclear why this would need to be done with a script in the first place. Try an array formula to copy form results instead.
